# WCF Service return value from internal web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a project where we have a client app calls a WCF service (OuterService). The OuterService internally calls another web service (InnerService). OuterService has methods who's return types are defined in InnerService. When the client calls a web method of OuterService with one of these InnerService return types, the OuterService call crashes.

If I change the return type of the OuterService webmethod to a basic type such as string, or int, the OuterService webmethod works without error. If I define a DataContract type in OuterService and use that as the OuterService webmethod return type, that will work too.

Has anyone ever defined a WCF service like this, that calls another web service and uses the types from that InnerService as return types for the webmethod of the OuterService? If so, what is the trick for making this work?

Comment: You will need to provide a code sample, as I have done this in the past with no problem.

Comment: Hi Frank: Shortly after posting this, I found that I could get a successful call to the OuterService WebMethod when one of the properties of the InnerService type were not populated. The property in question is a collection. Everything except for that collection appears to flow through to the client with no problem. So I am thinking my problem is specific to that collection property, or one of its child elements.

Comment: @SkipMunk Please provide code samples, especially of the collection property. Is it of type IEnumerable? That might be an issue - guessing blindly with no source code being available. What type does the collection contain? Is this type declared in the inner service only hence not part of the data crontract? And/or not serializable?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @QualityCatalyst, The error messages were either "No endpoint", or "Service ended prematurely", depending on what I would do to the "InnerService".

Comment: What was happening in this case was that the "InnerService" is instantiated in the "OuterService" constructor, as an object of one class of the "InnerService". All subsequent calls to the InnerService are made via this instance from the OuterService constructor. I commented that line out of the OuterService constructor and changed the OuterService "Get" method to instantiate the InnerService reference at the calling method, execute the target inner method, and return the data to the client. This worked perfectly. I don't think I could post enough code to illustrate the entirety of the problem.

Comment: I was preparing a non-proprietary version of the suspect code when I stumbled on to the solution.